# pyqt5 scroll area, how to add label

Tags: python, pyqt5

I created a GUI interface, for a code I am writing, on Qt creator I am almost done with the program, but I want to display the results of calculations done in a list in a Scroll Area by adding labels to the scroll Area container. typically to use whatever is created on Qt creator all I need to do is call it using self.NameAddedInInterface. what I have been trying to do is this

```
class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        self.m = TimeIndependent()
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        loadUi("UI.ui",self)

        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 & Matplotlib Example GUI")
        ## Results
        test = QLabel("god only knows")
        self.ContainerSimulated.addWidget(self.test)

        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.MplWidget.canvas, self))
app = QApplication([])
window = MatplotlibWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Just trying to add a label to the scroll area created in Qt creator. but I get this when I try running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...\main.py", line 85, in <module>
    window = MatplotlibWidget()
  File "C:...\main.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.ContainerSimulated.addWidget(self.test)
AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'addWidget'
```

How can I simply add labels into the the scroll area, to form a lsit?
this is the qtui file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>641</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>780</width>
          <height>175</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>16777215</width>
          <height>175</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="currentIndex">
         <number>3</number>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>StepFunction</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_5">
          <item row="0" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
            <property name="text">
             <string>                Vmax</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="2">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
            <property name="text">
             <string>                       B</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="2" column="3">
           <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxSRange">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>150</width>
              <height>29</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
            <property name="text">
             <string>                 Vmin</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="3" column="1">
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="PlotStepFunction">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Plot</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="1">
           <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxVmin">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>150</width>
              <height>29</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="2" column="1">
           <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxVo">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>150</width>
              <height>29</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="1">
           <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxVmax">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>150</width>
              <height>29</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="3">
           <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxLenB">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>150</width>
              <height>29</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="2">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
            <property name="text">
             <string>                       A</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="2" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
            <property name="text">
             <string>                    Vo</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="2" column="2">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_15">
            <property name="text">
             <string>              Range</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="3">
           <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxLenA">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>150</width>
              <height>29</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="5" rowspan="3">
           <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
            <property name="frameShape">
             <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="frameShadow">
             <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="4" rowspan="4">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="PIc">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>60</width>
              <height>60</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string/>
            </property>
            <property name="pixmap">
             <pixmap>StepImage.jpg</pixmap>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Quadratic</string>
         </attribute>
         <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>40</x>
            <y>10</y>
            <width>701</width>
            <height>121</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
           <item row="0" column="9">
            <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxQB0">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>29</width>
               <height>29</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>16777215</width>
               <height>29</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="1">
            <widget class="QTextEdit" name="BoxQB4">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>16777215</width>
               <height>29</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="7">
            <widget class="QTextEdit" name="BoxQB1">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>16777215</width>
               <height>29</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="8">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_12">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Ex°</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="4">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Cx²</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Ax4</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="3">
            <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxQB3">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>16777215</width>
               <height>29</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="6">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_11">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Dx¹</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="5">
            <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxQB2">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>16777215</width>
               <height>29</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="2">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Bx³</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_13">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Range</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="1">
            <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="BoxQXRange">
             <property name="maximumSize">
              <size>
               <width>16777215</width>
               <height>29</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="7">
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="PlotQuadraticFunction">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Plot</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="Schrodinger">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Schrodinger</string>
         </attribute>
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
          <item row="1" column="2">
           <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>40</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_14">
            <property name="text">
             <string>                m=</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="1">
           <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>100</width>
              <height>29</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="plainText">
             <string>6.626068E-34</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="4">
           <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>40</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="3">
           <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>40</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="1">
           <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
            <property name="text">
             <string>h^2/m =1</string>
            </property>
            <property name="checked">
             <bool>true</bool>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="2" column="1">
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="ButtonCalculate">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Calculate</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_3">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Results</string>
         </attribute>
         <widget class="QWidget" name="horizontalLayoutWidget">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>9</x>
            <y>29</y>
            <width>741</width>
            <height>91</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
           <item>
            <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
             <property name="widgetResizable">
              <bool>true</bool>
             </property>
             <widget class="QWidget" name="ContainerSimulated">
              <property name="geometry">
               <rect>
                <x>0</x>
                <y>0</y>
                <width>365</width>
                <height>87</height>
               </rect>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QScrollArea" name="Theoretical">
             <property name="widgetResizable">
              <bool>true</bool>
             </property>
             <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_3">
              <property name="geometry">
               <rect>
                <x>0</x>
                <y>0</y>
                <width>364</width>
                <height>87</height>
               </rect>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QWidget" name="horizontalLayoutWidget_2">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>10</x>
            <y>10</y>
            <width>741</width>
            <height>21</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
           <item>
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Simulated Results</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Theoretical</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="MplWidget" name="MplWidget" native="true">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>400</width>
        <height>400</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="Label_State">
      <property name="text">
       <string>State:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MplWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>mplwidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: change  `self.ContainerSimulated.addWidget(self.test)` to `self.ContainerSimulated.setWidget(self.test)`

Comment: thanks, but i get basically the same error: AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'setWidget'

Comment: I assumed that ContainerSimulated was the QScrollArea and I'm clearly wrong, so if you want help provide a [mcve]. shows the UI.ui

Comment: I added the ui.ui file. I verified that ContainerSimulated  is not a QScrollArea, at leas thats what i understand from lines 415 and 419. I changed the name and it seemed to work, thanks